# How to display image of an image url from firebase realtime database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So i was able to display the image url but what i need is to be able to display the image itself. Is it possible?[image][image]

I havent tried creating a code for it yet since i'm not that familiar yet at all with javascript and firebase but this is the code i used in retrieving the data and as well as displaying it in a modal:

HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <label class="labs">Donation ID: </label>
                <input type="text" id="DonationId" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">User ID: </label>
                <input type="text" id="UserId" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="FName" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Organization: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Org" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Contact Person: </label>
                <input type="text" id="ContPer" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Contact Number: </label>
                <input type="text" id="ContNum" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Type: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Type" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Date: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Date" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Time: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Time" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                 <label class="labs">Purchase Date: </label>
                <input type="text" id="PDate" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Expiration Date: </label>
                <input type="text" id="EDate" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Weight: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Weight" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Note: </label>
                <textarea id="Note" readonly="readonly"></textarea> <br>

                <label class="labs">Attached Image: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Img" readonly="readonly"> <br>

                <label class="labs">Status: </label>
                <input type="text" id="Stat" readonly="readonly">
```

JS code:

```
function AddItemToTable(id,uid,name,org,contPer,contNo,type,date,time,pdate,edate,weight,note,image,status){
                let trow = document.createElement("tr");
                let td1 = document.createElement('td');
                let td2 = document.createElement('td');
                let td3 = document.createElement('td');
                let td4 = document.createElement('td');
                let td5 = document.createElement('td');
                let td6 = document.createElement('td');
                let td7 = document.createElement('td');
                let td8 = document.createElement('td');
                let td9 = document.createElement('td');
                let td10 = document.createElement('td');
                let td11 = document.createElement('td');
                let td12 = document.createElement('td');
                let td13 = document.createElement('td');
                let td14 = document.createElement('td');
                let td15 = document.createElement('td');
                let td16 = document.createElement('td');

                newDonationList.push([id,uid,name,org,contPer,contNo,type,date,time,pdate,edate,weight,note,image,status]);
                td1.innerHTML = ++num;
                td2.innerHTML = id;
                td3.innerHTML = uid;
                td4.innerHTML = name;
                td5.innerHTML = org;
                td6.innerHTML = contPer;
                td7.innerHTML = contNo;
                td8.innerHTML = type;
                td9.innerHTML = date;
                td10.innerHTML = time;
                td11.innerHTML = pdate;
                td12.innerHTML = edate;
                td13.innerHTML = weight;
                td14.innerHTML = note;
                td15.innerHTML = image;
                td16.innerHTML = status;

                td15.classList += "statusField";
                td4.classList += "nameField";
                td5.classList += "organizationField";
                td8.classList += "typeField";

                trow.appendChild(td1);
                trow.appendChild(td2);
                trow.appendChild(td3);
                trow.appendChild(td4);
                trow.appendChild(td5);
                trow.appendChild(td6);
                trow.appendChild(td7);
                trow.appendChild(td8);
                trow.appendChild(td9);
                trow.appendChild(td10);
                trow.appendChild(td11);
                trow.appendChild(td12);
                trow.appendChild(td13);
                trow.appendChild(td14);
                trow.appendChild(td15);
                trow.appendChild(td16);

                var ControlDiv = document.createElement("td");
                ControlDiv.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="manage-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCenter" onclick="FillModal('+num+')">VIEW</button>'

                trow.appendChild(ControlDiv);
                tbody.appendChild(trow);

            }

            function AddAllITemsToTable(Donation) {
                num=0;
                tbody.innerHTML="";
                Donation.forEach(element => {
                    AddItemToTable(element.id, element.uid, element.fullName, element.organization, element.contactPerson, element.contactNo, element.type, element.dateAdded, element.dateAddedTime, element.datePurchased, element.dateExpired, element.weight, element.notes, element.imageUrl, element.donationStatus);
                });
            }

            function GetAllDataRealtime() {
               const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users');

                onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => {
                    var Donations = [];

                    snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
                        userSnapshot.child("donation").forEach((donationSnapshot) => {
                            Donations.push(donationSnapshot.val());
                        });
                    });

                    AddAllITemsToTable(Donations);
                })

            }

            window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime;

            var ModDid = document.getElementById('DonationId');
            var ModUid = document.getElementById('UserId');
            var ModName = document.getElementById('FName');
            var ModOrg = document.getElementById('Org');
            var ModContPer = document.getElementById('ContPer');
            var ModContNo = document.getElementById('ContNum');
            var ModType = document.getElementById('Type');
            var ModDate = document.getElementById('Date');
            var ModTime = document.getElementById('Time');
            var ModPDate = document.getElementById('PDate');
            var ModEDate = document.getElementById('EDate');
            var ModWeight = document.getElementById('Weight');
            var ModNote = document.getElementById('Note');
            var ModImage = document.getElementById('Img');
            var ModStatus = document.getElementById('Stat');

            window.FillModal=(index) => {
                if(index==null){
                    ModDid.value = "";
                    ModUid.value = "";
                    ModName.value = "";
                    ModOrg.value = "";
                    ModContPer.value = "";
                    ModContNo.value = "";
                    ModType.value = "";
                    ModDate.value = "";
                    ModTime.value = "";
                    ModPDate.value = "";
                    ModEDate.value = "";
                    ModWeight.value = "";
                    ModNote.value = "";
                    ModImage.value = "";
                    ModStatus.value = "";
                }
                else{
                    --index;
                    ModDid.value = newDonationList[index][0];
                    ModUid.value = newDonationList[index][1];
                    ModName.value = newDonationList[index][2];
                    ModOrg.value = newDonationList[index][3];
                    ModContPer.value = newDonationList[index][4];
                    ModContNo.value = newDonationList[index][5];
                    ModType.value = newDonationList[index][6];
                    ModDate.value = newDonationList[index][7];
                    ModTime.value = newDonationList[index][8];
                    ModPDate.value = newDonationList[index][9];
                    ModEDate.value = newDonationList[index][10];
                    ModWeight.value = newDonationList[index][11];
                    ModNote.value = newDonationList[index][12];
                    ModImage.value = newDonationList[index][13];
                    ModStatus.value = newDonationList[index][14];
                    
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an image rather than show its URL as text, you'll need to use a `img` element and then set is `src` attribute.

So first change the HTML for the image to:

```
<label class="labs">Attached Image: </label>
<img id="Img"> <br>
```

And then in the code:

```
ModImage.src = newDonationList[index][13];
```

Also see:

- [How to display image with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript)
- [How to display dynamic url image in html from which created by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341721/how-to-display-dynamic-url-image-in-html-from-which-created-by-javascript)